# SQL check current day

Tags: php, mysql, sql, datetime

I want to check if the current year/month/day/week/hour is the same as the dateTime saved in the db.

- The current dateTime is: 2013-12-15 12:02:19
- The db dateTime is: 2013-12-15 12:00:00

This is my query that checks the year/month/day/week:

```
$query_topics = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM topics WHERE day(startTime) = day(CURDATE()) and month(startTime) = month(CURDATE()) and day(startTime) = day(CURDATE()) and week(startTime) = week(CURDATE())") or die (mysql_error());
```

This one works but when I add hour to the query he will give me back null rows.
This is the query with year/month/day/week/hour:

```
$query_topics = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM topics WHERE day(startTime) = day(CURDATE()) and month(startTime) = month(CURDATE()) and day(startTime) = day(CURDATE()) and week(startTime) = week(CURDATE()) and hour(startTime) = hour(CURDATE())") or die (mysql_error());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try replacing `CURDATE()` with `NOW()`:

```
hour(NOW())
```

Comment: I think you're looking for `hour(NOW())`.